# Android Sign APK With Upload Certificate (How To Ensure Correct Fingerprint)

Tags: java, android, visual-studio, xamarin, signing

This is Google's documentation on signing an APK:
https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

The documentation seems fairly straight forward. I've been able to piece together process from various other pages, and from Stack Overflow threads. But, after I've signed the APK, the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint in the APK is wrong, which implies that I have not signed the APK with the correct certificate.

> You uploaded an APK that is not signed with the upload certificate.
>   You must use the same certificate. The upload certificate has
>   fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: FINGERPRINT ]
>
> and the certificate used to sign the APK you uploaded have
>   fingerprint:
>
> [ SHA1: FINGERPRINT ]

My question is: **how do I make sure that my generated keystore is using the Upload Certificate from the Google Play Console?**

Here's what I did:

- Sign up as a Google Developer and created an app in the console
- Clicked on App Signing and downloaded the Upload Certificate (upload_cert.der)
- I then used keytool to both import the certificate and create the keystore: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool" -importcert -file upload_cert.der -keystore [appname].jks -alias "[appname]" . This succeeded in that it did create the keystore file. But, my gut feeling is that this is where the process went wrong. I don't think the certificate was imported.
- I checked the keystore with this command: "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool" -list -keystore [appname].jks and **the outputted fingerprint is completely different to my upload certificate's fingerprint**.
- I also tried:
  "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool" -importcert -file upload_cert.der -genkey -v -keystore [appname].jks -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias [appname]
- This succeeded and pushed out the .jks keystore file
- I generated an unsigned APK (Archive)
- In Visual Studio, I clicked "Distribute ..." -> Ad Hoc
- Imported my keystore file and clicked "Save As" which seemed to sign my APK
- Then, I uploaded it to the store but the store rejected it saying it had the wrong fingerprint.
- So, I used the key too to check the fingerprint in the RSA file . "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161\bin\keytool" -printcert -file [appname].RSA .The fingerprint was wrong.

**What steps am I missing?**

*Note: the Google doc says that this is the process for manually signing:*

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#sign-manually

keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.jks
-keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000 -alias my-alias

apksigner sign --ks my-release-key.jks --out my-app-release.apk my-app-unsigned-aligned.apk

*But these steps don't use the upload certificate in any way...*

> All updates to your existing app must now be signed with your upload
>   key. This will allow Google to verify your identity.

This makes complete sense. In essence, all I'm trying to do is sign the APK with my upload key from Google. I have the upload key. But, the step that Google hasn't documented is how to turn the upload key in to a keystore so that I can sign the APK with the keystore. It looks straight forward enough, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have lost your private keys. The Upload Certificate is the Certificate for your first upload app and created when you upload it. You need to use that `.keystore` file to sign your app.

> how do I make sure that my generated keystore is using the Upload Certificate from the Google Play Console?

It's not possible. According to Google [Manage your app signing keys](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en):

> Certificate: A certificate contains a public key as well as some extra
>   identifying information about who owns the key.

The certificate doesn't contain the private key. So it could not used to create keystore.

The only way to solve this is that reset the upload key as said at the end of above [article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en).

You refer to the following guides for publish app in xamarin:
[Publishing to Google Play](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/publishing/publishing-to-google-play/?tabs=vswin)
[Signing the Android Application Package](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/?tabs=vswin)
[Manually Signing the APK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/signing/manually-signing-the-apk)

Comment: You are right. What happened was that I created a keystore, signed my APK with it, uploaded it to the store, and then deleted the keystore. So, the problem wasn't that I needed to import the upload certificate in to the keystore. That's not even possible. The issue was that I needed to use the original keystore. My question is really phrased incorrectly and I need to change it in order for the question to be answered properly.

Comment: I more or less thought the process was a lot more complicated than it was. What confused me was that the play store gives me an app certificate and an upload certificate. I thought that they wanted me to sign my app with one of those before uploading it. I couldn't figure out why they wanted me to create an ad hoc keystore. But, now I realise it's because that first keystore is considered the ultimate and only keystore that is ever to be used for the lifespan of the app.

Comment: I guess I still don't get why they even bother to show us the certificates. They looked important, but Google manages those, so what's the point of even showing them to us?

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper It usually uses `asymmetric cryptography` to sign the apk, such as RSA. And it has a paired public key and private key. For example, if you have many app and they use different private key to sign, you could find the correct private key by the certificates shown in google.

Comment: @BillyLiu-MSFT hi there, I have enabled google app signing with an existing app `.keystore` , the problem im facing is that my current release build show a different `SHA-1` key, although I signed it with the same `.keystore`